# How do I remotely debug the executable file of an installed application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt(v=vs.100).aspx) which is AWESOME and a GODSEND for dealing with "Welp it purrs like a kitten in dev but once I get it released it crashes and burns like the Chernobyl reactor".

But I need to be able to take it one step further.
I know about remote debugging but this is a desktop application, nothing like a server or anything like that. I need to know if it is possible for me, using VS 2010, to remote into a client machine, navigate to the criminal .exe file, open it into VS2010, and debug it remotely like that, and if it is possible, how I go about achieving it.

Comment: Have you read Set Up the Remote Tools on the Device (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.120).aspx) and 
Start the Remote Debugging Monitor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf8k2h6a(v=vs.120).aspx)?  Sounds like you'll also need some of the information in 
Remote Debugging Across Domains (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: In what way regular remote debugging does not satisfy your requirement?

Comment: If my understanding of it is correct, regular remote debugging is where I attach to a process already running on another machine. In my case, I need to be able to run the application that has already been installed on the target client machine so that I can see the execution from start to finish. There isn't a way to do that (of which I am aware) when you launch the offending application and then connect to the process remotely.